# How do Google and Samsung's "Find My Device" service can bypass Android's Secured Lock Screen?

Tags: lock-screens, encryption, find-my-device

As I know, when the phone is locked that means it has been encrypted.

So how do Google and Samsung's "Find My Device" service [bypass Android's Secured Lock Screen](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/7-ways-bypass-androids-secured-lock-screen-0165540/)? Does it mean they have our decryption key?

Comment: When the phone is locked it doesn't necessarily mean it's encrypted. Usually it's the other way around.

Comment: @Izzy, isn't it File-Based Encrypted with direct boot (https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) ?

Comment: As I wrote: Encryption will certainly require a "lock" (password) – but a lock doesn't require encryption. Screen lock usually doesn't: while you lock your screen, the file system stays "decrypted".

Comment: @Izzy, even the file system stays "decrypted" but the rest still stay encrypted right ? We still need the key to decrypt in order to fully use, don't we ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When locking the screen one simply locks the screen, nothing else. If encrypted, the file system always "stays encrypted" – even if the device is unlocked and you're working with it. Knowing the encryption key and passphrase, the OS can access it. As soon as you shut down, the passphrase is forgotten and the file system thus inaccessible. But that has nothing to do with locking/unlocking the screen. IOW, "bypassing the lock screen" doesn't touch encryption, AFAIK.